# React router history issue

Tags: reactjs, react-router

When I hit "http://localhost:8080/" I get "Cannot GET /"

I have implemented "browserHistory" as follow:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Router, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import Wrapper       from './../components/wrapper.jsx';
import Home          from './../components/home.jsx';
import Projects      from './../components/projects.jsx';
import SingleProject from './../components/projectContent/singleProject.jsx';
import About         from './../components/aboutUs.jsx'

ReactDOM.render((
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={Wrapper} >
            <IndexRoute component={Home} />
            <Route path="projects" component={Projects} />
            <Route path="projects/:id" component={SingleProject} />
            <Route path="about" component={About} />
        </Route>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-router-prototype",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "react router prototype",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack -d --watch",
    "build": "webpack -p",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --inline --content-base . --history-api-fallback"
  },
  "author": "Alessandro Santese",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.13.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.13.2",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "react": "^15.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.0",
    "react-router": "^2.6.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^3.10.0",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/public');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/app');

var config = {
  entry: APP_DIR + '/config/routes.jsx',
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module : {
    loaders : [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: APP_DIR,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
            presets: ['es2015']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: [ 'style', 'css', 'sass' ]
      }, 
      {
        test: /\.json$/, 
        loader: "json-loader"
     }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
      historyApiFallback: true
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

wrapper.jsx

```
import React from 'react';

import Header from './header.jsx';
import Footer from './footer.jsx';

class MobileMenu extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
        <div className="mobile-menu">
          <ul>
            <li>list item</li>
            <li>list item</li>
            <li>list item</li>
            <li>list item</li>
            <li>list item</li>
            <li>list item</li>
            <li>list item</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    )
  }
}

class Wrapper extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open: false
    };
  }
  toggleWrapper() {
    this.setState({open: !this.state.open});
  }
  render () {
    const toggle = this.state.open ? ' open' : '';
    return (
        <section className={"wrapper" + toggle}>
        <div className="inner-wrapper">
          <MobileMenu />
            <div className="content">
            <Header action={this.toggleWrapper.bind(this)}/>
            {this.props.children}
            <Footer />
          </div>
        </div>
        </section>
    );
  }
}

export default Wrapper;
```

I would like to test the current state of my application on the server but I need to sort this issue first.

Comment: you havevn't defined any path for wrapper component so it will take `/' as the base route and then it tries to find /aldemar which doesn't match any routes

Comment: This seems to be a problem with server-side routes. If the user starts their visit from the root of the site (example.com), and then navigates to one of your routes from the browser, it would probably work as React Router knows how to handle that case. Otherwise, the browser would need to make one request to the server for one of your routes (e.g. /projects). If the server-side route doesn't exist, it returns a 404.

You could implement a wildcard router on the server? The same HTML is always going to be served so it doesn't matter.

Comment: I have updated the routes configuration but I still get the same error... I know I need a server configuration but this should be fine view it on "localhost:8080" without # in the URL correct?

Comment: Do I still need to create a server side configuration even if I am just running the application from localhost?